# RKObjectManager sharedManager getObjectsAtPath Optionally save in persistent storage

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, restkit, restkit-0.20

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/pathpattern/:userId" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
         NSLog(@"success");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"fail");
    }];
```

I am using `RKManagedObjectStore` using `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:withConfiguration:options:error`

The defined pattern gives different data for different "userId", I want to save data in sqlite data base for only one userId, for other userIds I don't want to save it.
Any suggestion how this could be achieved using same `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`RKDynamicMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html) with the response descriptor for that path. With that mapping you can analyse the incoming data and decide which mapping you actually want to apply to the received data.

Note that 'not saving' the new objects to Core Data means using an `RKObjectMapping` instead of `RKEntityMapping`.

Answer (score 1):

you don`t init your shared manager. try this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourURL];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    RKObjectManager *operation = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:httpClient];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:kURLToDownloadData 
                                           parameters:nil
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
 NSLog(@"success"); 
}
                                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"fail");
}
```